# Longest Path in a acyclic, directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a known algorithm which finds the longest path in an acyclic, directed graph like the one below?

For this example, the algorithm should calculcate a longest path of 28m
[image: graph]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths

Comment: Thanks to @Casteels. So the answer would be to negate the weights and apply dijkstra?

Comment: There are a couple of problems with applying a shortest path algorithm with negative weights.  Dijkstra's algorithm needs non-negative weights, and it assumes a known "source" as starting point (and finds the shortest path to a fixed target).  So the proposed duplicate is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Use dynamic programming on the partial order implied by the graph.
- To simplfy, you can first order the graph topologically.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$